# ldap Naming Exception

Tags: ldap

am trying to get the user details from ADAM Active Directory.
i used the following java code.

```
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class SimpleQuery {
public static void main(String[] args) {

            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    attribute="street";
    query="(&(cn=ldap1))";

    try {
        String url = "ldap://172.16.12.178:389/cn=users,dc=sharepoint,dc=com";
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
        DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(env);

        String[] attributeFilter = {"cn", "givenName", "SN", "street", "streetAddress", "postalAddress", "postOfficeBox", "l", "st", "postalCode", "c", "telephoneNumber", "homePhone", "mobile", "pager", "mail", "objectCategory", "objectClass", "userAccountControl"};
        SearchControls ctrl = new SearchControls();
        ctrl.setReturningAttributes(attributeFilter);
        ctrl.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        NamingEnumeration enumeration = context.search("", query, ctrl);
        while (enumeration.hasMore()) {
            SearchResult result = (SearchResult) enumeration.next();
            Attributes attribs = result.getAttributes();
            NamingEnumeration values = ((BasicAttribute) attribs.get(attribute)).getAll();
            while (values.hasMore()) {
              if (output.length() > 0) {
                output.append("|");
              }
              output.append(values.next().toString());
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception : "+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.print(output.toString());
}

public SimpleQuery() {}}
```

and am getting this exception:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C09
06DC, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be comp
leted on the connection., data 0, v1db0 ]; remaining name ''
```

Is there any attribute i need to put?.

Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're attempting the operation anonymously and it isn't permitted. You need to set Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL/SECURITY_CREDENTIALS in the `env` before attempting the operation.

Comment: thanks, you are right. i got the result using Principal & Credentials attribute.